# How do I create a variable to check last time hook_cron() implemented from a custom module was ran?

Tags: 7, hooks, cron, configuration

We have a custom module for which we need to run on a daily basis. I am not sure  it is working, as I am unable to store the time correctly.

Does the following code allow me to create a variable, and use it to store the last time cron ran?

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  if (variable_get('mymodule_last_run', 0) <= strtotime('-1 day')) {
    // Omissis.
    variable_set('mymodule_last_run', time());
  }
}

function mymodule_info($options) {
  $variable['mymodule_last_run'] = array(
    'title' => t('Last Run', array(), $options),
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'default' => t(time(), array(), $options),
  );
}
```

Comment: @NoSssweat i have modified the question so that is more clear what i am asking for. I believe Shawn's answer lead me in the correct direction, but i want to verify that when i call hook_info i am using the correct steps. I noticed that the time() was not storing in the variable i am using mymodule_last_run so i want to validate that the hook_info is correct.

Comment: The questions seems clearer, now. The problem is not how to run a cron hook every 3 months, but implementing the correct hook required from a third-party module.

Comment: To make it clear to future close-voters: This question is not a duplicate because it came out to asking how to use the Variable module for the persistent variables used by a module; the fact the persistent variable is used in `hook_cron()` is irrelevant. The answer for the other question doesn't explain how a module should use the API exposed from the Variable module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing the wrong hook. What you are trying to implement is [`hook_variable_info()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/variable/variable.api.php/function/hook_variable_info/7), used from the [Variable](http://drupal.org/project/variable) module. Hook name apart, that hook implementation seems correct.

Instead of using `variable_set()`, you should use [`variable_set_value()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/variable/variable.module/function/variable_get_value/7). The equivalent of `variable_get()` is [`variable_get_value()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/variable/variable.module/function/variable_get_value/7).

See the project page for more information about how to use the module API,  [Variable API](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/variable/variable.module/group/variable_api/7) for a list of available functions, and [variable.api.php](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/variable/variable.api.php/7) for a list of hooks used from the Variable module.

The code you want to use should be similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_cron() {
  if (variable_get_value('mymodule_last_run') <= strtotime('-1 day')) {
    // Omissis.
    variable_set_value('mymodule_last_run', REQUEST_TIME);
  }
}

function mymodule_variable_info($options) {
  $variable['mymodule_last_run'] = array(
    'title' => t('Last Run', array(), $options),
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'default' => 0,
  );
}
```

Notice that `variable_get_value()` doesn't need the default value, since it gets it from the `hook_variable_info()` implementation done from your module. If you need to use a different default, you call the function as `variable_get_value('mymodule_last_run', array('default' => REQUEST_TIME)`.

As for your original code, you don't call `t()` as `t(time(), array(), $options)` because:

- The first argument of `t()` must be a literal string, not the value returned from a function
- `time()` returns an integer; even if it would be casted to a string, `t()` doesn't change an integer in any way, for example returning `'1,000'` when receiving `1000` as first argument.

If the Variable module is expecting a string (e.g. `'19700318T19:00'`) as default value for a variable of type *datetime*, you need to use a different function.