# How do I call function inside .module file from linux system crontab?

Tags: 7

my module add queue item from hook_cron(). Now i want to execute one by one queue item with custom function [mymodule_indexing_queue()] inside mymodule.module file.

Like:

```
in mymodule.module
---------------------------------------------------------------
function mymodule_indexing_queue() {
  $mymodule_queued = DrupalQueue::get('my_indexing_walker');
  $numberOfIndexQueueItems = $mymodule_queued->numberOfItems();

  if ($numberOfIndexQueueItems > 0) {
    $action = $mymodule_queued->claimItem();
    if ($action) {
      process_queue_start_walking($action->data);
      $mymodule_queued->deleteItem($action);
    }
  }
}
```

Now i want to call mymodule_indexing_queue() function from crontab -e without hook_cron().

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`drush eval`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/php-eval/). You can call your function like: `drush eval "mymodule_indexing_queue();"`

There are probably better ways to do what you're trying to do though. You can write your own drush commands, use drupal's built in batch processor, or even just use the same hook_cron function with some conditions for time checking to run the queueing/executing work separately.

See:

- https://www.thirdandgrove.com/best-practices-for-using-drupals-cron-system-hook_cron
- [How do I create a variable to check last time hook_cron() implemented from a custom module was ran?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208430/how-do-i-create-a-variable-to-check-last-time-hook-cron-implemented-from-a-cus)

Comment: thanks for reply. 
But, i apply an alternate method to do that since i don't want drush. I Update my question with my method.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a menu item for your function using hook_menu in your .module file. Then you can add that menu path to your crontab using wget or however you want to do it